# mysql getting count of components viewed in given month

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm trying to get the number of times a particular item has been viewed in a given month.

I have a viewed table that looks something like this:

```
id_component viewed_date
1 | 2013-03-25 11:40:04
3 | 2013-03-26 11:41:04
4 | 2013-04-05 11:42:04
2 | 2013-04-07 11:43:04
3 | 2013-04-12 11:44:04
4 | 2013-04-17 11:45:04
3 | 2013-04-18 11:46:04
2 | 2013-04-20 11:47:04
4 | 2013-04-22 11:48:04
```

I have a component table something like this:

```
id, component_name, component_desc, component_price, folder_id
1 | muffler | ford focus muffler | 99.00 | 3
2 | air filter| ford focus air filter | 12.00 | 3
3 | oil filter| ford focus oil filter | 6.00 | 3
4 | wiper | ford focus rear wiper | 6.00 | 3
```

My current query is this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(viewed_date) AS vmonth, YEAR(viewed_date) AS vyear, COUNT(*) AS vcount  
FROM viewed AS V
RIGHT JOIN components AS C on V.id_component = C.id 
WHERE id_component IN (SELECT id FROM components WHERE folder_id = '3')
GROUP BY YEAR(V.viewed_date), MONTH(V.viewed_date)
ORDER BY V.viewed_date
```

What I want to get back is this:

```
vmonth = march, vyear = 2012, vcount = 1, id = 1, component_name = muffler, etc. etc.
vmonth = april, vyear = 2012, vcount = 1, id = 2, component_name = air filter, etc. etc.
vmonth = march, vyear = 2012, vcount = 1, id = 3, component_name = oil filter, etc. etc.
vmonth = april, vyear = 2012, vcount = 2, id = 3, component_name = oil filter, etc. etc.
vmonth = april, vyear = 2012, vcount = 3, id = 4, component_name = wiper, etc. etc.
```

I'm getting this

```
vmonth = march, vyear = 2012, vcount = 4
vmonth = april, vyear = 2012, vcount = 9
```

I'm not getting the joined data or the data on the individual components... just the monthly totals for the folder

It's gotta be something stupid I'm doing... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting only two rows because you group by a pair (year,month) of which you have only two distinct values in your viewed table. You need to add third column - id_component to the group by to get your desired result. Also it seems you don't want to see 0's for every combination of month, year and id, so you need INNER JOIN instead of outer one.

This query should give you desired output:

```
SELECT v.vmonth, v.vyear, v.vcount, c.id, concat( c.component_name, ', etc. etc.' ) AS component_name
FROM components c
JOIN ( SELECT MONTHNAME( viewed_date ) AS vmonth, YEAR( viewed_date ) AS vyear, id_component, count( * ) AS vcount
       FROM viewed
       GROUP BY vmonth, vyear, id_component ) v 
ON v.id_component = c.id
```

Comment: So basically I did it backwards! LOL  Thanks for that, it worked like a charm!